# Quick Edit is not enabled even after adding the clienttemplate.js as described below

Tags: sharepoint-server, quick-edit

We have added clienttemplate.js in Schema.xml in the required view. But still the Quick Edit is not enabled even after all the OOB features also. Can you please suggest any solution for this?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Is it enabled in your list settings (advanced settings)?

Comment: Yes All the options that are to be enabled directly using Advanced settings are enabled

Comment: Which view have you created? Can you add a screenshot? Does it work for other lists?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new list, check if Quick Edit is disabled.

If not, please make sure the new list has same columns with the problematic list, then use Content and Structure feature to move the items from the problematic list to the new list.

You can find the Content and Structure feature as Site Settings->Content and Structure under Site Administration. If the Content and Structure is missing under Site Administration, you need to enable SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure feature at site collection level.